# Passing line number from vim to external command

Tags: vim

I am using VIM and I would like to pass the current line *number* to an external program.

something like this:
`map <F3> :!mycmd <linenumber><CR>`

I tried to substitute `<linenumber>` for `line('.')`, `line(".")`, `.` and others, but nothing seems to work.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `map <F3> exec(":!mycmd ".line("."))`. Didn't test it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use `:execute` to use a variable or expression in your mapping:

```
nnoremap <F3> :execute ":!echo " . line('.')<CR>
```

Comment: A little simpler:  nnoremap <F3> :execute ":!echo" line('.')<CR>